# Why won't A New Order start?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, ps4, skyrim-dawnguard

I got Skyrim Remastered for the PS4 a couple weeks ago, and I have played through a decent portion of it with surprisingly few bugs/problems. However, after completing Bloodline, I have encountered a very serious bug.

I retrieved Serana from Dimhollow, and then took her back to her home (with Lydia as a follower also). Upon rejecting Harkon's (I want to play as Dawnguard this time), I was transported out of the castle like normal. The problem is, the next quest, A New Order, wont start, and Isran has no dialogue option to start it. Also, I can't get the vampire attack to happen.

I've tried:

- Walking around the boat
- Walking around the tower
- Waiting a few days
- Saving/Reloading after turning in Serana
- 'Killing' Isran then waiting for him to be peaceful again

I even made a save just before the castle, and reloading from there won't fix it. I started the questline many days ago, so reloading from there is out of the question. My only other option will be reloading to before entering Dimhollow, which I will try later tonight.

Obviously, being on the PS4, I can't use any of the console command solutions one might find on google. If anyone Could help me get past this bug, I will forever be in your debt. If you need more details, just ask.

*TL;DR*
A New Order won't start, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately it seems there is no way to get past the bug after you have already found Serana. Instead, load a save before entering Dimhollow Crypt. Then have Lydia leave right before opening Serana's coffin. This has fixed the bug for me.